# Need particular data from link opened in webbrower

Tags: python-3.x

https://examplesite.org/?status=success&request_token=xyz

Assuming above mentioned link is already opened in google chrome web browser.How can i get value of request_token which is "xyz" from link by using programming in python.could you please help me with code?Please provide solution for any browser, not just google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.request.GET.get('request_token')
```

This will "get" the variable from the "GET" dictionary, and return the 'variable_name' value if it exists, or a None object if it doesn't exist.